# Where to put data validation in ADR pattren?

Tags: laravel, design-patterns

Where to put data validations in [Action–domain–responder](https://github.com/pmjones/adr) architectural pattern?
What I am trying to do for now is something like this:

```
|- app/  
   |- Console/  
      |- Commands/  
   |- Events/  
   |- Exceptions/  
   |- Http/  
      |- Middleware/  
   |Blog
      |- Actions/  \\Sned data to a Service then recive data to be handled by a Responder
      |- Domain/  
          |- Models/  
          |- Services/  
      |- Responders/   
   |- Jobs/  
   |- Listeners/  
   |- Providers/  
|- database/  
   |- factories/  
   |- migrations/  
   |- seeders  
|- config/  
|- routes/  
|- resources/  
   |- assets/  
   |- lang/  
   |- views/
```

For validation I want to use  [FormRequest](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#form-request-validation) to handle that.
Should I put it inside **Actions**?

Answer (score 0):

You can put anywhere your form request, you just need to use this class where do you use. for example,

```
use App\Http\Requests\UserUpdateRequest;

public function update(UserUpdateRequest $request, $id)
{
```

I hope this will help.